# How to disambiguate two instances of template classes with the same template parameter name

Tags: c++, templates

I'm stuck with an issue and I'm not sure how to phrase it as a one-liner.
The issue is about templates.
Here is the situation:
In my code I have two classes with the same template parameters:

```
template< typename TEMPLT_PRM1,
          typename TEMPLT_PRM2>
class MyC_A;
template< typename TEMPLT_PRM1,
          typename TEMPLT_PRM2>
class MyC_B;
```

Now one of the functions of class MyC_A receives an argument of type MyC_B and that's where the issue I'm facing is:

```
template< typename TEMPLT_PRM1,
          typename TEMPLT_PRM2>
class MyC_A
{
private:
//....
public:
    void foo( MyC_B<TEMPLT_PRM1, TEMPLT_PRM2> & bInst )
    {
         //....
    }
};
```

So then I instantiate an object of type MyC_A and another object of type MyC_B. Here is the instantiation:

```
MyC_A<MyC_C, MyC_D> myc_a_inst;
MyC_B<MyC_E, MyC_F> myc_b_inst;

myc_a_inst.foo( myc_b_inst);
```

This gives me the error saying that the function definition is not found. Meaning that the compiler is looking for void foo( MyC_B < MyC_C, MyC_D > ) and it cannot find it. Instead my MyC_B object instance is of the type MyC_B< MyC_E, MyC_F >.

This I believe is coming from the fact that template parameters for both classes MyC_A and MyC_B is the same and that I cannot change.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue is very much appreciated.

BTW, I also tried the following with no luck.

```
template< typename TEMPLT_PRM1_B,
          typename TEMPLT_PRM2_B>
void foo( MyC_B<TEMPLT_PRM1_B, TEMPLT_PRM2_B> & bInst )
```

Comment: Your last try should work. http://ideone.com/a73hUt

Comment: The latter, with a templated `foo`, is the right approach. What was the issue there?

Comment: Please never say "doesn't work": give error messages!

Comment: You guys are correct. I think end of the day exhaustion got the best of me. The errors were coming for a different function call which I missed doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have created myc_b_inst with the typenames MyC_E & MyC_F. In the function foo the parameter passed uses typenames MyC_C & MyC_D (If you don't get it look carefully at the definition of the function. You used the same typenames that class MyC_A uses, that is in this case, MyC_C & MyC_D). So the parameters don't match. This is a possible reason for error. Try :

```
MyC_B<MyC_C, MyC_D> myc_b_inst;
```

instead of

```
MyC_B<MyC_E, MyC_F> myc_b_inst;
```

& see the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arpan. That piece of code was actually compiling just fine. I missed that the error was coming for another function with the same issue.